# Reactjs tutorial - Without 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache' new comment disappear and show

Tags: node.js, data-binding, reactjs, browser-cache, cache-control

Referring to the [comment box React tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html), in the node server `server.js`, when this line is removed from Post handler:

```
res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
```

when adding comment again, the comment would quickly show and disappear, and only shown again later (probably when next pulling happens), different from the correct "optimistic comment" behaviour. Quoting:

> It'll also have a few neat features:
>   Optimistic commenting: comments appear in the list before they're saved on the server so it feels fast.

How does Cache-Control work on the server and in the browser? Why would this happen?